# lessc using Ruby instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, less, npm

I am using lessc to compile my css in a node application. LESS was installed via NPM.

Currently the output of

```
lessc --version
```

is

> lessc 1.3.3 (LESS Compiler) [Ruby] 2.3.2

How do I get it to say

> lessc 1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [Javascript]

in order to compile my css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the issue. I had the Rubygem version of less installed, and it was overriding the NPM installation of less. Uninstalling the gem allowed the NPM version of less to run when compiling less.