# Bootswatch.less compile error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, bootswatch

I'm getting this error when trying to compile (`lessc bootswatch.less > bootstrap.css`) a clean install of Bootswatch:

> [...] error evaluating function `fadein`: Object # has no method 'toHSL' (Less::Parse Error).

It was working last week..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838107/lessc-using-ruby-instead-of-javascript

Answer (score 0):

See also [less undefined method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300298/less-undefined-method-error).

The bootswatch file should be compiled with Bootstrap together. So create a index.less file, which contains the following code:

```
@import "bootstrap.less"; //from the Bootstrap source code
@import "variables.less"; //from your bootswatch theme
@import "bootswatch.less";
```

And than compile that file: `lessc index.less > bootstrap.css`

Comment: It ended up being a conflict between compiler paths. Thanks.